# Order mysql results in order for a specific id to be first

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP pagination in order to retrieve some products. The thing is that when I click a product I'm getting the content via AJAX. Everything works fine but I also need to have a direct link to the product, and there's no product page (only the html block retrieved by AJAX).

So I've implemented the link to the listing with #product-alias hash. If I have the anchor in the page I simulate the click on it and it works fine, the content of the product is displayed.

The problem comes when my product is on another page. I thougt that the solution would be to force the query to retrieve the product on the first page.

The current query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products Product {JOINS} WHERE Category.id = 1, Product.active = 1 LIMIT 0,10;
```

What can I add to the conditions (or ORDER) in order to have the product with the id = 12 in theese results.

Hope there's enough info here.
Any other ideas are well recieved!

Thanks!

Comment: You could do `ABS(id - 12)` and sort by that

Comment: You only want the items with productid=12? Is that correct?

Comment: @ToBe please post that as an answer to mark it as correct. I HUG YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a temporary id showing the relative distance from your target id and sort by that value. In this case the id **12**:

```
SELECT *, ABS(Product.id - 12) AS idOrder 
FROM products Product
{JOINS} 
WHERE Category.id = 1, Product.active = 1 
ORDER BY idOrder ASC
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: As requested, my lazy asssed comment as a full fledged answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use it in the WHERE. Assuming the ProductId is 12 then use below syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM products Product {JOINS}   
WHERE Category.id = 1, Product.active = 1 AND Product.ProductId=12 LIMIT 0,10;
```

If you want to skip the 12 records you could use this

```
SELECT * FROM products Product {JOINS} 
WHERE Category.id = 1, Product.active = 1 LIMIT 12,10;
```

Comment: Hey Kay, the above query will only get the product.

Comment: Hey! Your questions is "What can I add to the conditions (or ORDER) in order to have the product with the id = 12 in theese results".

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't said that it should be the only one... I would have been to simple.

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand what you are after?

Comment: Check ToBe's answer and you will understand

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM products Product {JOINS} WHERE Category.id = 1, Product.active = 1 OR Product.id = 12 LIMIT 0,10;
```

This should work I suppose?

Comment: This wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. If the server is mysql you could use:

    SELECT * FROM products Product {JOINS} WHERE Category.id = 1, Product.active = 1 ORDER BY field(id, 12) DESC LIMIT 0,10;

Comment: @LucianVasile was it useful?